# Scrape CSS style along with their HTML tags using Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've been trying to scrape both the HTML tags, its contents, and CSS styles that are applied to it from an external website. I am currently using a combination of BeautifulSoup & Selenium. The HTML tags and contents can be found by using

```
soup.find_all() or driver.find_elements_by_xpath()
```

However, for css style, I haven't figured out a way.

[Sample Inspect Screenshot from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVlBC.png)

For instance, as you can see in the above screenshot (ignore Korean), When I select

```
<div class="ab_sub_heading">
```

I want to be able to reach and scrape at the same time that we can see on the right in the Inspect page.

```
.ab_sub_heading { width: 80%, margin-top: 3.3333em; ...}.
```

Is there any fast way to do this on BeautifulSoup / Selenium?
I'm open to using other libraries or frameworks if needed as well. Thank you.